# Getting undesired error on clicking the custom exit button in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I have created a Winforms application in C#, where I have provided **Exit** button. And on the click of that button I execute custom function, where I have written

```
Application.Exit();
```

But it's showing error:

[image]

Comment: this might help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7912052/system-invalidoperationexception-due-to-collection-modification-on-call-to-appli

Comment: Copy the exception detail to the clipboard, use the stack trace to determine where it was thrown, then post the relevant code from that section.

Comment: It is showing error on the same line Application.Exit();

Comment: The exception is telling you that you are modifying a collection within a loop--like a foreach loop.  Look for any uses of a collection when you process the Close event...